# Remove the DC offset

Tags: signal

I struggle to design a *rectangular signal generator*, without using op-amp or LM, with adjustable oscillation frequency and peak to peak output voltage. Also, how can I improve my circuit, and **remove the DC offset**?

[image]

Comment: You can look at the block diagram and schematic of the 555, which can easily be made adjustable in frequency and duty cycle. Then implement that with discrete components, if that is your goal.

Comment: https://spectrum.ieee.org/build-your-own-giant-555-timer-chip

Comment: simple suggestion, why not use a split rail? e.g. +/- 5V or whatever voltages you want.